# Modify bytes in image to add black zones left and right

Tags: c#, image, byte, padding

I have a `byte[]` object which contains the bytes of an image. I need to pad the image adding black zones to the left and right.
My image is 512 height and 384 width and I need to make it 512X512, that is, I need to add 128 colums, 64 to the left and 64 to the right.

I think I need to first copy all image bytes to columns 65 to 448 (that makes my 384 width image), then add 64 columns to the left and 64 columns to the right.

I'm not quite sure how to do this, I would imagine a nested for will suffice but not sure.

I'm programming in C#

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us what format the images is in and if it's the raw image data or if it's an compressed/encoded form such as jpeg or png

Comment: The images could be 8 bpp, 16bpp, 24bpp or 32bpp (uncompressed). I also have compressed images but I decompress them and then save uncompressed, that's not an issue.

Comment: So when you say that, do you mean that the byte array just contains bytes like this: RGBRGBRGB ?

Comment: if it is 24bpp yes. If it is 16bpp it contains 2 values per pixel and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tested this with a raw image generated by Photoshop and it seems to work OK. Obviously it's designed to only work for your specific case as I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but I'm sure you could improve upon it :)

```
public byte[] FixImage(byte[] imageData,  int bitsPerPixel)
{
    int bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / 8;
    List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageData.Length; i += 384 * bytesPerPixel)
    {
        data.AddRange(new byte[64*bytesPerPixel]);
        data.AddRange(imageData.Skip(i).Take(384 * bytesPerPixel));
        data.AddRange(new byte[64 * bytesPerPixel]);
    }
    return data.ToArray();
}
```

If you end up using more complicated formats than raw byte arrays, it may be worth investigating using the GDI functions in System.Drawing. Let me know if you want an example of that.

Comment: Thanks John, your code seems to address the first 512 pixels of the image, I need all the image

Comment: @Matimont Have you actually tested it? This does the entire image. Your image is comprised of 384 pixel rows, if you will. For a 24bpp image, the for loop goes something like 0, 1152, 2304, etc. which sets i to the start of each row in the byte array. For each row in the image, it adds 64 pixels at the start, the 384 pixels of the row and a further 64 pixels.

Comment: I have uploaded an example input and output in the raw forms accepted/generated by the application and the corresponding PNG form here: https://www.sendspace.com/file/04i4j6          Code used: `byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\test.raw"); data = FixImage(data, 24); System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test2.raw", data);`

Comment: Unless you mean you have a two-dimensional (byte[][] or byte[,]) array?

Comment: Thanks John, no, it is not two dimensional. I will try again and let you know. I got 1024 elements only. The Image is 512 rows and 384 columns

Comment: @Matimont If you have any issues, send me the raw image and I'll have a look in the morning (I'm in the UK)

Comment: No need :) I already got it working, when I translated your code to match mine, I misunderstood the ImageData.lenght piece. Now is working. Thanks!